# How to build a colormap that covers multiple scales in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

I have a dataset that covers two different scales and I need to display details for the finer scale as well some characteristics for the "big picture". The best example I can think of where this type of problem is encountered is in ocean topography data, where the details of the coast are highlighted as well as the general trends for the deep ocean, all with one colormap. While there are colormaps available for such applications, there doesn't seem to be much information on how to generate them.

In addition, with the application of nonlinear colormaps, the colorbars seem to remain linear. For example if my data covers the range from [0 1] but 95% of the variance lies between [0 0.0075], the colorbar still goes from [0 1] on a linear scale and it's hard to correlate the colors with the colorbar. Meaning 0.0075% of the colorbar is variable, whereas the remaining is essentially one color, which seems pointless.

Sticking with my example, I have data that ranges from [0 1] but 95% of the variance lies between [0 0.0075]. I need the colormap to cover the full range, but highlight the variance between [0 0.0075]. At the same time, I'd like 95% of the colorbar to cover the color variability corresponding to 95% of the variance.

Can someone tell me how to generate a colormap that covers multiple scales effectively?

EDIT: Here is a simple example

```
tmp = peaks;
index = find(abs(tmp)<0.2);
new = 0.2.*rand(1,length(index));
tmp(index) = new;
imagesc(tmp)
colorbar
```

The colorbar covers the full range of data, as desired, but you can not see any of the variance at the fine scales.

[image: coarse scale]

If you simply limit the color axis

```
caxis([-0.2 0.2])
```

You can see the variance at the fine scales

[image]

I'd like to capture both of these scales with one image, and one colormap/colorbar. Using the colorbar from the first image as a reference, the range would go from approx [-6 8], but the colormap would go from [darkblue skyblue] for values [-6 -0.2], [skyblue lightred] for values [-0.2 0.2], and [lightred darkred] for values [0.2 8]. The color variability would target the smaller scales, while red/blue gradients would target the coarse scales. I believe both scales would be well resolved visually.

The colorbar might then be given as a piecewise linear scale, such that the [skyblue lightred] takes up 80% of colorbar? I'm not sure what would be best, but I know if it was a linear scale over the full range, the colorbar would be about 49% [darkblue skyblue], 2% [skyblue lightred], and 49% [lightred darkred], which doesn't help correlate color with values at the fine scale.

Maybe this isn't the best approach...hence why I'm here...this approach was just to show the concepts my question in trying to display multi scale data.

EDIT2: The example I gave here is simply piecewise linear...I believe the concept should translate to a nonlinear colormap as well, where I should be able to define any range of colors over any set of scales, linear, nonlinear, piecewise, whatever I desire.

Comment: I think that the question would benefit immensely by addition of some images. Do you happen to have any at hand to share and show what you desire and what you currently see with the linear color map?

Comment: Its a crude method; but have you tried defining a custom color map? Using the [link] (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)

For example: 
<code>
map = [0, 0, 1;  0, 1, 0.4; 1, 0, 0.5;  0, 0, 0.5;  0, 0, 0.6;  0, 0, 0.7 ; 0, 0, 0.8;  0, 0, 0.9;  0, 0, 1];
caxis manual
colormap(map)
colorbar'
</code>

You get to define your own number of segments in an image.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to split the jet colormap in half and use log indexing to stretch the middle of it, so that you have better contrast on the values near zero.

```
nColor=1000; % number of colors in the colormap

nJet = 1000; % needs to be even, high number for better interpolation
mapJet = jet(nJet);
kHalf = round(nJet/2);
map1 = mapJet(1:kHalf,:);
map2 = mapJet((nJet-kHalf+1):end,:);

% tweak 0.4 and 50 so that you are happy with the result
idx = log(linspace(0.4,50,kHalf))/log(2);
idx = (idx-min(idx(:)))/(max(idx)-min(idx))*(kHalf-1)+1;

map3 = arrayfun(@(x) interp1(size(map1,1):-1:1,map1(:,x),idx(length(idx):-1:1))', 1:3,'UniformOutput', false);
map3 = cell2mat(map3);

map4 = arrayfun(@(x) interp1(1:size(map2,1),map2(:,x),idx)', 1:3,'UniformOutput', false);
map4 = cell2mat(map4);

map = [map3;map4];

tmp = peaks;
index = find(abs(tmp)<0.2);
new = 0.2.*rand(1,length(index));
tmp(index) = new;
m = max(abs(tmp(:)));

imagesc(tmp)
caxis([-m m])
colormap(map)
```

It produce the following result. You can of course tweak the parameters or the transfer function (here log) so that the result better fits your need:

[image]